# Shrink-to-fit menu items - first item grows

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a menu of a pre-specified width.

I want each menu item to shrink-to-fit with its contents, with the exception of ONE, which then fills up the remaining space in the menu.

Like this:

---

```
                                                       Fill | item | item | item
```

---

So far the closest I've come to achieving this effect is by using `display:table-cell` in the css code for each menu item. But the problem is unless I define a width for the item's, they all expand to take up the same amount of width in the table.

---

```
      Fill      |      item      |      item      |      item      |      item
```

---

Is there any way to have the item spaces shrink to fit the item and have the fill item just fill up the rest of the div?

Comment: So do you want to use a table or not?

Comment: I don't want to use a table, but I want to achieve the above described effect, where one item fills up the space that isn't taken up. Fills up, meaning takes up all of it.

Comment: It seems like you're not giving a very clear reason. Why do you **NEED** to fill the space? What's wrong with (eg) a set of floated divs in a parent? what's so important about the filling in? You'ld be surprised what can make the problem easier, when we know all about the problem.

Comment: Oh. I was hoping for a visual effect (which is why it's not all that important that I get this) where I could hover over the "fill" item and have the rest of the menu light up, since the "fill" item is just special that way. (like a "links" menu item in a WordPress theme)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make last cell of a row in a table occupy all remaining width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060933/how-to-make-last-cell-of-a-row-in-a-table-occupy-all-remaining-width)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a float instead? Just reverse the order of your menu items.

```css
#menubar {
  background-color: lime;
  width: 100%;
}
.menuitem {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

/* Clear float */
#menubar:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  clear: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="menubar">
  <div class="menuitem">item</div>
  <div class="menuitem">item</div>
  <div class="menuitem">item</div>
  <div class="menuitem">item</div>
  <div class="menuitem">fill</div>
</div>
```

---

Alternate way to use `display: inline-block` that fills the width:

```css
#menubar {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}
.menuitem {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: aqua;
}
.filled {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="menubar">
  <div class="menuitem filled">fill
    <div class="menuitem">item</div>
    <div class="menuitem">item</div>
    <div class="menuitem">item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The only downfall with this second method is that the menu item's are actually contained within the first menu item / filled.  It does the trick for filling `width:100%`...  If they are drop-down menus you will probably want to do some z-index work and collapse borders / set padding / etc...

Comment: The problem is that menuitem "fill" doesn't exapand to take up the entirety of the rest menubar; it just floats right.

Comment: Strange question:  So you need the fill to truly fill the menubar?

Comment: Try the second float method...  (bottom half) ...  if that doesnt work for you really the only cross browser/safe method left would be to use tabless...     Why does the menu/fill "have" to "fill" the space?

Comment: Part two is a reasonable workaround. I don't think there's going to be another way so I'm accepting your answer. thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

For those who want to do it with a table, you can give the first "td" a class and set it to a ridiculously large width, then it will push and force the other columns to shrink as much as it can.
It works because tables can't expand more than the width to which they were set.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
table td {
    border:solid 1px #000;
}
table td.fill {
    width:9999em;
    text-align:right;
}
table {
    width:300px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr><td class="fill">Fill</td><td>item</td><td>item</td><td>item</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

In the old example that worked in Firefox and IE only I set the "td" width to 0, then it shrinked the column as much as it could.

You can set all columns to shrink-to-fit by setting the td width to something small, like 1px when you don't set the table width, this works in Chrome, Firefox and IE.

```
table td {
  width:1px;
}
```

You might want to set `white-space:nowrap;` too, otherwise all the words will wrap, or give the `td` some larger `width`

Comment: I gave you +1 after I tested in IE. Then I realized, this was not supported in chrome. Haven't tested other browsers, but this is a major flaw. As of July 2012, Chrome accounts for 27% of browser usage, IE 23%, Firefox 19%, and Safari 15%.

Comment: @MrJones thanks for you note Mr Jones, I don't remember if it worked in chrome when I made it, I might have only tested it in firefox and IE and sort-of expected Opera and Chrome to also work. **I fixed the example above** by reversing the logic, instead of setting all of the td's to have width 0, I set the width of .fill to be ridiculously large, now it works in Chrome, Opera, Firefox, IE5.5-9

Comment: +1 because the good old "ridiculously large width" trick works when given in `px` or `em` as you did here, but fails in Safari when given as `100%`. I lost days on this one.

Answer (score 7):

One way I've dealt with this issue is to apply `width: 1px;` to every `<TH>` where I'd like their cells to shrink. Then on each individual cell where I want to shrink to the content, I apply `white-space: nowrap;`. This prevents the cell from actually shrinking to 1px.
I'm currently using this method on a table of financial figures so I'm not sure if it works with longer paragraphs of text.

Comment: This method worked for me in Firefox 16.0.2, but in Chrome 23.0.1 it went back to the standard td width - the same width as it had without these CSS attributes. Good idea with the white-space attribute though.

Comment: Worked for me on Firefox and Chromium. Most people will probably use: `table tr > :not(:last-child) { white-space: nowrap; width: 1px;}`

Answer (score 2):

## Welcome to the year 2014

### Let's get flexible

We can now look forward to the future when **[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)** is standard. Currently a [W3C Candidate Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/), Flexbox is currently limited by [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) (importantly, only IE 11 supports the current model).

### Flexible navigation with a larger first-child

#### The markup

```
<nav>
    <a href="#">Fill</a>
    <a href="#">Item</a>
    <a href="#">Item</a>
    <a href="#">Item</a>
</nav>
```

#### The flex

The regular links get `flex: 0 0 auto`:

- `0` - don't grow
- `0` - don't shrink
- `auto` - don't let the text overflow (`auto` is supposedly default, but text overflows without it set)

The first link gets `flex: 1 0 auto`:

- `1` - take up the remaining width
- `0` - don't shrink
- `auto` - don't let the text overflow

```
nav {
  display: flex;
}
nav a {
  flex: 0 0 auto; 
}
nav a:first-child {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

[This Flexbox guide is very helpful.](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

#### The combination (with added fluff)

Run the snippet below

```js
/* 
For the purpose of this demo:
toggle active class on click
*/

$('nav a').on('click', function() {
  $('nav a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
/* Foundation Properties */
nav {
  display: flex;
}
nav a {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
nav a:first-child {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  text-align: right;
}

/* Fluff Properties */
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
}
nav {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #3f51b5;
}
nav a {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #c5cae9;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #3f51b5;
  padding: 4em 1em 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
nav a.active {
  color: #fce4ec;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #fce4ec;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <a href="#" class="active">Fill</a>
  <a href="#">Item</a>
  <a href="#">Item</a>
  <a href="#">Item</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using tables

```
<style type="text/css">

#menubar {
    width:100%;
}

.FillBar {
    width:100%;
    text-align:right;
    background-color:gray
}

</style>



<table id="menubar">
<tr>
<td class="FillBar">Fill</td>
<td>item</td>
<td>item</td>
<td>item</td>
<td>item</td>
<td>item</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Just add style (padding/spacingp/etc) or whatever else you need...

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what @cjezowicz is talking about, you can use `white-space` together with making one cell `width: 100%` to achieve the effect you're looking for:

```
<div id="row">
   <div class="cell fill">Fill</div>
   <div class="cell shrink">Item</div>
   <div class="cell shrink">Item</div>
   <div class="cell shrink">Item</div>
   <div class="cell shrink">Item</div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">

   div#row { display: table; width: 100%; }

   div.cell { display: table-cell; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; }

   div.cell.fill { width: 100%; }

   div.cell.shrink { white-space: pre; }

</style>
```

Then, if you need to force a set width for any of the shrunken cells, use the `min-width` on that cell.