# How do I make width of a column (containing text with spaces) fit to its contents in HTML table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I was recently trying to figure out how to make a cell/column fit it's width to it's content. I found a question on stackoverflow that seemed to perfectly fit the bill for what I was looking for: [How to make width of a column fit to its contents in HTML table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305140/how-to-make-width-of-a-column-fit-to-its-contents-in-html-table)

My issue was when I added a space to the content of the cell, it added a return and bumps the next word down a line.

So this code:

```
<div style="max-width:700px;">
<table border="1">

    <tr><td width="1px">Papua New Guinea:</td><td >Goroka</td></tr>
    <tr><td colSpan="2">this is a loooooooooooooooong text</td></tr>
</table>
```

Produces this table:

http://cl‍.ly/image/2F0V1J3V2u22

Instead, this is what I was wanting:

http://cl‍.ly/image/2m0a0m0t0L0v

I realize that putting `&nbsp;` in instead of spaces would fix this. My issue is that this is being used in a mail newsletter template, and the text in that cell is dynamic. Sometimes there are spaces, sometimes not. For example yesterday it said Bolivia, today Papua New Guinea which is when I noticed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try

```
td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QkNqk/

You can also use

```
td {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

To let newlines in the source create breaks. So as long as you don't have a line break,the text will stay in one line