# Shrinking width of middle div in a series of inlines elements

Tags: html, css

I have the following arrangements of inline elements in my layout:

```
***********************************************
*     Div 1      *       Div 2       * Button *
* Dynamic text   *  Some static text *        *  
***********************************************
```

My problem is that when the content inside div 1 is long the button falls out of place.

```
******************************************
*     Div 1           *    Div 2         *         
* A long dynamic text * Some static text *********** 
*                     *                 *  Button *  
****************************************************
```

The desire effect is to shrink the Div 2's width and make the text to break into two lines.

```
***********************************************
*     Div 1           *    Div 2     *        *
* A long dynamic text *  Some long   * Button *
*                     *  static text *        *  
***********************************************
```

How would I go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: One way to achieve this is to style each div as `display:table-cell`, and follow @Roimer's solution for fitting table cell widths to their content. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14084773/1241736

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions guys. I ended up wrapping the divs in a table, and gave the outer <td> elements a width of 1%, and this worked!

Answer (score 0):

Place all 3 `div`s in a wrapper. Make the wrapper `position: relative`. Then make the `div` with the button have `height: 100%`.