# Position the last HTML Table Cell to the right side of the Body

Tags: html, css, html-table

Updated question to include the code***
I tried a few things to get them to line up but haven't had luck. May need to try using col but I am not sure how to go about it. I can post my code if anyone is interested. *Updated question to include the code***

This is how I want it to look:
[image: This is how I want it to look]

This is how it currently looks:
[image: This is how it currently looks]

```css
#printPage {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 910px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 0.4%;
}

#tableheadtitle {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

#tabledataname {
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: white;
}

#tablehead1 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

#tabledata1 {
  background-color: white;
}

#section1 {
  margin-top: 1%;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
  width: 670px;
  height: 114px;
  /* clear: both;
        page-break-after: always; */
}

#header {
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  width: 75%;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
  margin-top: 0.3%;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 8pt;
}

td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 8pt;
}

#data1 {
  background-color: white;
}

#s1total {
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11pt;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#totalnum {
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

#section2 {
  margin-top: 0.5%;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
  width: 670px;
  height: 925px;
}

#header2 {
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

#s2total {
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 11pt;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

#totalnum2 {
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>time card</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="printPage">
    <table id="table1">
      <colgroup>
        <col span="1" style="width:100%; ;text-align:left;">

      </colgroup>

      <tr id="tablerow1">
        <th id="tableheadtitle">TIMECARD</th>
        <th id="tablehead1">Employee Signature</th>
        <th id="tablehead1">Authorized</th>
      </tr>
      <tr id="tablerow1">
        <td id="tabledataname">John Doe - JXD</td>
        <td id="tabledata1"><input type="text"></td>
        <td id="tabledata1"><input type="text"></td>

      </tr>

    </table>

  </div>

  <div id="section1">
    <p id="header">WEEKLY HOURS</p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Clocked</th>
        <th>Regular</th>
        <th>Overtime</th>
        <th>Incentive</th>
        <th>Holiday</th>
        <th>Personal</th>
        <th>Vacation</th>
        <th>Off-Clock</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="data1">4.35</td>
        <td id="data1">0.00</td>
        <td id="data1">0.00</td>
        <td id="data1">0.00</td>
        <td id="data1">0.00</td>
        <td id="data1">0.00</td>
        <td id="data1">0.00</td>
        <td id="data1">0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <p id="s1total">Total</p>
      <br>
      <p id="totalnum">4.35</p>
    </table>

  </div>
  <div id="section2">
    <p id="header2">WED 10/3/2018</p>
    <table>

      <tr>
        <th>Shift start</th>
        <th>Time In</th>
        <th>Time Out</th>
        <th>Break 1</th>
        <th>Break 2</th>
        <th>Break Hours</th>
        <th>Clocked Hours</th>
        <th>Payable</th>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="data1">9:00 AM</td>
        <td id="data1">8:52 AM</td>
        <td id="data1">-</td>
        <td id="data1">11:30 AM- <br>12:00 PM</td>
        <td id="data1">-</td>
        <td id="data1">0.5</td>
        <td id="data1">4.85</td>
        <td id="data1">4.35</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>Incentive</th>
        <th>Holiday</th>
        <th>Personal</th>
        <th>Vacation</th>
        <th>Off-Clock</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>

      </tr>

    </table>
    <p id="s2total">Total</p>

    <p id="totalnum2">4.35</p>

    <p id="header2">THUR 10/4/2018</p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Shift start</th>
        <th>Time In</th>
        <th>Time Out</th>
        <th>Break 1</th>
        <th>Break 2</th>
        <th>Break Hours</th>
        <th>Clocked Hours</th>
        <th>Payable</th>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="data1">9:00 AM</td>
        <td id="data1">8:52 AM</td>
        <td id="data1">-</td>
        <td id="data1">11:30 AM- <br>12:00 PM</td>
        <td id="data1">-</td>
        <td id="data1">0.5</td>
        <td id="data1">4.85</td>
        <td id="data1">4.35</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>Incentive</th>
        <th>Holiday</th>
        <th>Personal</th>
        <th>Vacation</th>
        <th>Off-Clock</th>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p id="s2total">Total</p>

    <p id="totalnum2">4.35</p>
    <p id="header2">FRI 10/5/2018</p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Shift start</th>
        <th>Time In</th>
        <th>Time Out</th>
        <th>Break 1</th>
        <th>Break 2</th>
        <th>Break Hours</th>
        <th>Clocked Hours</th>
        <th>Payable</th>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="data1">9:00 AM</td>
        <td id="data1">8:52 AM</td>
        <td id="data1">-</td>
        <td id="data1">11:30 AM- <br>12:00 PM</td>
        <td id="data1">-</td>
        <td id="data1">0.5</td>
        <td id="data1">4.85</td>
        <td id="data1">4.35</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>Incentive</th>
        <th>Holiday</th>
        <th>Personal</th>
        <th>Vacation</th>
        <th>Off-Clock</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
    <p id="s2total">Total</p>

    <p id="totalnum2">4.35</p>
    <p id="header2">SAT 10/6/2018</p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Shift start</th>
        <th>Time In</th>
        <th>Time Out</th>
        <th>Break 1</th>
        <th>Break 2</th>
        <th>Break Hours</th>
        <th>Clocked Hours</th>
        <th>Payable</th>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="data1">9:00 AM</td>
        <td id="data1">8:52 AM</td>
        <td id="data1">-</td>
        <td id="data1">11:30 AM- <br>12:00 PM</td>
        <td id="data1">-</td>
        <td id="data1">0.5</td>
        <td id="data1">4.85</td>
        <td id="data1">4.35</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>Incentive</th>
        <th>Holiday</th>
        <th>Personal</th>
        <th>Vacation</th>
        <th>Off-Clock</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
    <p id="s2total">Total</p>

    <p id="totalnum2">4.35</p>
    <p id="header2">SUN 10/7/2018</p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Shift start</th>
        <th>Time In</th>
        <th>Time Out</th>
        <th>Break 1</th>
        <th>Break 2</th>
        <th>Break Hours</th>
        <th>Clocked Hours</th>
        <th>Payable</th>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="data1">9:00 AM</td>
        <td id="data1">8:52 AM</td>
        <td id="data1">-</td>
        <td id="data1">11:30 AM- <br>12:00 PM</td>
        <td id="data1">-</td>
        <td id="data1">0.5</td>
        <td id="data1">4.85</td>
        <td id="data1">4.35</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>Incentive</th>
        <th>Holiday</th>
        <th>Personal</th>
        <th>Vacation</th>
        <th>Off-Clock</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p id="s2total">Total</p>

    <p id="totalnum2">4.35</p>
    <p id="header2">MON 10/8/2018</p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Shift start</th>
        <th>Time In</th>
        <th>Time Out</th>
        <th>Break 1</th>
        <th>Break 2</th>
        <th>Break Hours</th>
        <th>Clocked Hours</th>
        <th>Payable</th>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="data1">9:00 AM</td>
        <td id="data1">8:52 AM</td>
        <td id="data1">-</td>
        <td id="data1">11:30 AM- <br>12:00 PM</td>
        <td id="data1">-</td>
        <td id="data1">0.5</td>
        <td id="data1">4.85</td>
        <td id="data1">4.35</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>Incentive</th>
        <th>Holiday</th>
        <th>Personal</th>
        <th>Vacation</th>
        <th>Off-Clock</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
    <p id="s2total">Total</p>

    <p id="totalnum2">4.35</p>
    <p id="header2">TUE 10/9/2018</p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Shift start</th>
        <th>Time In</th>
        <th>Time Out</th>
        <th>Break 1</th>
        <th>Break 2</th>
        <th>Break Hours</th>
        <th>Clocked Hours</th>
        <th>Payable</th>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="data1">9:00 AM</td>
        <td id="data1">8:52 AM</td>
        <td id="data1">-</td>
        <td id="data1">11:30 AM- <br>12:00 PM</td>
        <td id="data1">-</td>
        <td id="data1">0.5</td>
        <td id="data1">4.85</td>
        <td id="data1">4.35</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>Incentive</th>
        <th>Holiday</th>
        <th>Personal</th>
        <th>Vacation</th>
        <th>Off-Clock</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
    <p id="s2total">Total</p>

    <p id="totalnum2">4.35</p>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ofwvq7td/

Comment: I will!!! Thanks so much it is perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep it simple, I only kept the relevant part.

First, as said, id are unique. Don't set the same id for more than one element. Personnaly, I avoid to use them abusively (only if I need to reference them directly in DOM manipulation or CSS design).

Also try to avoid duplicate CSS rules, if some elements share a design, wisely regroup their rules. Easy maintenance is a short and long-term goal.

Finally, as you can see, in the snippet below, I used semantic id and class names, to be able to find out what designs what later on.

```css
#printPage {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 910px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 0.4%;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

div#section-example {
  margin-top: 0.5%;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
  width: 670px;
  height: 925px;
}

div#section-example header {
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

table.example {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
  margin-top: 0.3%;
}

table.example th,
table.example td {
  vertical-align:top;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 8pt;
  /* The following rule (white-space) is used to allow the last cell   */
  /* to fill the remaining width.                                      */
  /* see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1060967/4375327                   */
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table.example th {
  /* padding to keep THs right aligned with TDs                        */
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

table.example td {
  padding: 5px;
}

table.example tr.last-row th,
table.example tr.last-row td {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

table.example tr.last-row th.total,
table.example tr.last-row td.total {
  /* The following rule (width) is used to allow the last cell to fill */
  /* the remaining width.                                              */
  /* see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1060967/4375327                   */
  width: 99%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="printPage">

  <div id="section-example">
    <header>WED 10/3/2018</header>
    <table class="example">

      <tr>
        <th>Shift start</th>
        <th>Time In</th>
        <th>Time Out</th>
        <th>Break 1</th>
        <th>Break 2</th>
        <th>Break Hours</th>
        <th>Clocked Hours</th>
        <th>Payable</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>9:00 AM</td>
        <td>8:52 AM</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>11:30 AM- <br>12:00 PM</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>0.5</td>
        <td>4.85</td>
        <td>4.35</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="last-row">
        <th>Incentive</th>
        <th>Holiday</th>
        <th>Personal</th>
        <th>Vacation</th>
        <th colspan=4>Off-Clock</th>
        <th class="total">Total</th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="last-row">
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td colspan=4>0.00</td>
        <td class="total">4.35</td>
      </tr>

    </table>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to answer this without being able to see the code. Something small I can think of off the top of my head is that they don't appear to be in the same container.

If you placed all items into a div and did something like display:flex; you should have them all organize in a row.

Comment: Yes I will, just let me know where you paste it. Preferably at https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: There you go, thank you also please look at the image I posted that shows how I want it to look. thanks